# Fading-out texture looks bad over the same solid texture when rendered

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, alphablending

I'm writing a mobile game for android, using OpenGL ES 2.0. Currently I'm trying to make a scroll with spells, that should in-game look like this:

[image: Scroll design]

It would be an element of GUI, where player could select spell which he currently wants to cast. As you can see there can be more spells, than scroll's width allows, so player should be able to scroll them left-right to show more. These near the edge should fade out.

My game has sort of two "layers": GUI and the game itself. I render both in single GUISurfaceView: the game-world in perspective projection and GUI in orthogonal, in front of the game-world. In fact every GUI element has the same mesh: flat plane made of two triangular faces. When I need rectangle I just modify scale matrix.

I figured I can achieve the effect above by having 3 layers of GUI:

1. foreground (it's fading with alpha):

[image: Left edge of the foreground].................................................................................................
[image: Right edge of the foreground]

2. spells below foreground:

[image: Fireball]
[image: Fireball]
[image: Fireball]
[image: Fireball]
[image: Fireball]
[image: Fireball]
[image: Fireball]
[image: Fireball]

3. background below spells:

[image: Left edge of the background]
[image: Middle background]
[image: Right edge of the background]

As you can see, edges of the background and egdes of the foreground are exactly the same, except the alpha channel. So they should align perfectly and allow for such fade-out effect. And they are - at least in Paint.NET (I uploaded .pdn file with all 3 layers of scroll [here](http://www.speedyshare.com/Znu7X/scroll-sample.pdn)). But not in rendered OpenGL. Instead, it looks like this (without any spell-icons):

[image: Rendered scroll]

As you can see, there are darker areas where foregrounds are gradienting with alpha. As if foreground and background weren't aligned perfectly. I absolutely can't understand why.

- I've made sure that models (planes) are in the same world coordinates (except Z) and have the same size (they're squares to be exact),
- I have alpha blending turned on and I sort models with alpha-blended textures by their distance to the camera,
- I've tried to turn off auto-generating of mipmaps, but it didn't help,
- I've checked the mesh of my plane and its UVMap for inaccurate numbers. In Wavefront the plane mesh looks like that:

  ```
  o Plane
  v 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
  v 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
  v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
  v 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
  vt 0.000000 1.000000
  vt 1.000000 1.000000
  vt 0.000000 0.000000
  vt 1.000000 0.000000
  vn 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
  f 2/1/1 1/2/1 4/3/1
  f 1/2/1 3/4/1 4/3/1
  ```
- my shaders look like this:

Vertex shader:

```
    uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;

    attribute vec4 aPosition;
    attribute vec3 aNormal;
    attribute vec4 aColor;
    attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

    varying vec4 vColor;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vPosition;
    varying vec2 vTexCoord;

    void main() 
    {
        vColor = aColor;
        vNormal = aNormal;
        vTexCoord = aTexCoord;

        vPosition = vec3(uMVMatrix * aPosition);
        gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
    }
```

Fragment shader:

```
    precision mediump float;

    uniform sampler2D uTexture;
    uniform bool uHasTexture;
    uniform vec4 uDiffuse;

    varying vec4 vColor;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vPosition;
    varying vec2 vTexCoord;

    void main()
    {
        vec4 texColor;
        if (uHasTexture)
            texColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord);
        else texColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

        vec4 color = vColor * texColor;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb * uDiffuse.rgb, texColor.a * uDiffuse.a);
    }
```

Do you have any ideas why does this happen? Maybe for some reason it just can't be done the way I figured? If so, could you suggest any other way to do this?

Comment: What blend function are you using?

Comment: When I create my Renderer object I call: `GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` and then `GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);`.

Comment: What is your clear color? You may not want to use blending when drawing the background texture. It looks like it might just be the clear color showing through the transparent parts of the background texture.

Comment: Well, the thing is, the background texture is fully opaque - of course in the parchment part, cause above and below the parchment there is transparency. My clear color is cornflower blue, but it doesn't show, because behind my scroll there is rendered my game-world - in the screen above I believe it's stone floor. And it's worth adding, that when I hide the first layer the scroll looks ok - no any darker areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your texture does not have the same colors as the texture beneath. I.e. the color bits are also fading, not only the alpha part.

Then you should use `GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE,GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` as your blending function.

Comment: It works! thank you very much. I must certainly read more about these two parameters...